# Adding custom UI behavior to controls via a Component

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer, custom-component

In my project, I have several controls that display a set of points on the screen. I would like to provide "lasso selection" functionality for all of these controls. To do this, I wrote a class called "Lasso", which takes care of tracking mouse movements, displaying the lasso, raising an event when the lasso is closed, etc. So far so good. But, in order to use the lasso, I must write code like this:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl {

    private Lasso lasso;

    public MyControl() {
        InitializeComponent();

        lasso = new Lasso();
        lasso.HookEvents(this);
    }
}
```

The "lasso.HookEvents" method takes care of hooking up the lasso to the mouse events for the host control.

What I would like to do is somehow provide a way for people to simply drag the "Lasso" component from the Toolbox onto their UserControl or Form at design time, and not worry about writing any code themselves; the lasso should magically "just work". Is there a way to do that ? I tried extending my Lasso class from Component, but I couldn't figure out how to get the Designer to generate the "lasso.HookEvents(this)" invocation automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, just capture the mouse events in the `Lasso` object.  If that's not possible or doesn't work: In your `Lasso` class, add a handler to the `Loaded` event, and in the handler run `this.HookEvents(this.Parent);`.

Comment: Unfortunately, my Lasso class extends Component, not Control; thus, it does not have a "Loaded" event. I don't want to extend Control because the Lasso does not have its own UI; it just provides UI behavior for the parent.